# Clipping Mask makes coloured box disappear

Tags: adobe-illustrator, clipping-mask

I'm having issues with Adobe Illustrator clipping mask.

I'm learning as I go and have a created a masking path to work with a coloured rectangle. However, whenever I select 'Make Clipping Mask', the coloured box goes white.

This hasn't happened to me before, so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong?

I've posted a gif to show you what I mean.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because the **colored box *is* your clipping mask.**

Clipping masks can not have fills.

If you want a colored background add *another* colored rectangle **behind** all the artwork, *then* make the clipping mask.

Whatever shape you use for a clipping mask should never have a fill. Well, you can add a fill. But as you've discovered, that fill will be removed when the object is set as a clipping mask.

Answer (score 2):

You can again fill the clipping mask by the options above activating edit clipping mask button.

Comment: Yeah, but please be aware that the technical standards don't define this behaviour. Also bit of a problem for the shading engine.